# azure bash: sudo: command not found

Tags: bash, azure

In tutorial of azure iot edge, there's a sample said that user is able to command "**sudo**" in Bash, however the other tutorial said that "**Permissions are set as regular users without sudo access**".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3n0E.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JG1F.png)

Also when I followed the tutorial command in azure bash(sudo), it didn't work, so I'm wondering if I've missed something?

By the way, the tutorials are all from the Microsoft.

Comment: If you are on an azure instance you may already be root, so sudo is not a supported command.

Comment: @GemTaylor Really appreciate! I'll try the other way

Answer (score 3):

This is mainly because you were running on a Debian system, which does not come with the sudo command to add it use the following steps:

```
su -

apt-get install sudo -y
```

After that you would need to play around with users and permissions. Give sudo right to your own user.

```
usermod -aG sudo yourusername
```

Comment: 4 years ago compared to 2023/06 I can ssh into my device, and issue the command which works.  Try to remote that command from my own program, and reports that "sudo" is not found.  I thinking i'm using the same userid as my program (learning here).